Blower motor works intermittently. Why?
Works one day, dead the next.
When I hit a bump sometimes it'll start working again.
Haven't been able to check it out yet. What could be going on with it?
Scion tC, 05

Two guesses that can be checked; worn out blower (19yrs old) or overheated blower motor wire(s). Plan on examining the blower motor and its wiring. An overheated ground connection may be the issue and easier to see as long as you can follow motor wiring to connections. Removing the blower motor for bench testing may reveal either damaged/burned connectors or its worn out.
